# MySQL order by the same order of values in IN clause

Tags: mysql

Here is the simple query with IN clause. But the problem is i need to get the output in the same order of the ids.

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(username) as users FROM usertable WHERE usr_id IN (54,68,46)`

For example if i pass 54,68,46 then the row with usr_id 54 should come first then 68 and then 46 should come. Is there any way to achieve this in MySQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `FIND_IN_SET` on order by clause to get the values in same order like this.

```
SELECT `username` as users FROM usertable WHERE usr_id IN (54,68,46) ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`usr_id`,"54,68,46")
```

But i don't know how to `GROUP_CONCAT` in the same order. If anybody gives the answer for that in these kind of simple approach, i can accept that answer.

Comment: Clever! Note that if the column is a string, use `POSITION` instead of `FIND_IN_SET`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ORDER BY` clause in [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(username ORDER BY user_id ASC) as users 
FROM usertable 
WHERE usr_id IN (54,68);
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't want in ASC or DESC order. I want in the same order passed in IN clause. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT group_concat(username order by case when usr_id=54 
                                           then 0
                                           when usr_id=68
                                           then 1
                                           when usr_id=46
                                           then 2
                                           else 3    
                                      end) as users 
FROM usertable
WHERE usr_id IN (54,68,46)
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/814a0/1)

Comment: It is showing the error as `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usertable' at line 1: usertable`

Comment: Did you copy the query from the SQLFiddle example? It it correct.

Comment: Ya it is working. But those values are dynamic. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: I'd just use [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_field) - see it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/814a0/2/0).