# Mysql select order results by parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, where-clause

table:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $playlist_table (
            `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            `options` text DEFAULT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta( $sql );


$playlist_id = array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "13" [1]=> string(2) "11" [2]=> string(2) "25" }

$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id, title, options FROM {$playlist_table} WHERE id IN (%d,%d,%d)", $playlist_id), ARRAY_A);
```

I get results returned:

playlist id 11, 13, 25

How can I have them returned in the order I specified? (13,11,25)

Comment: Look into groupby().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734524/mysql-order-by-the-same-order-of-values-in-in-clause). Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796083/8062035).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starter: your query has no `order  by` clause, so the ordering of the result is actually undefined. Whatever ordering you currently see is not guaranteed to be consistent over consecutive executions of the query.

So you do need an `order by` clause. In MySQL, you can conveniently use [string function `field()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) for this. This requires passing the list of values twice:

```
SELECT id, title, options 
FROM {$playlist_table} 
WHERE id IN (%d, %d, %d) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, %d, %d, %d)
```